# Infinite retries on XmlRpc IllFormedXmlRepsonse

Tags: c#, .net-4.0, xml-rpc

I am currently working on integrating two systems using the Cook Computing XmlRpc library and am getting some messy responses returned from one of these systems.

The developers of this system have assured me this is on their end and that the problem will not be fixed until the beginning of April. As you can imagine, if one system happens to get updated and the other returns a bad response I have a very serious sync issue.

Anyway, until April I basically have to retry every call to the system until it does not return an XmlRpcIllFormedXmlException. As this issue is completely intermittent and temporary it usually fails ~1-3 times before finally working however I have seen 10+ retries coming through so these figures are by no means a maximum.

The code I have written to handle this horrible scenario is beginning to worry me as I am effectively writing an infinite loop with exception handling for control flow but I cannot see any other way around it!

So my question: Is there anything inherently wrong with what I am doing and could this cause me some serious issues within the next month?

```
while(true)
{
    try
    {
        XmlRpcStruct data = // AnyDataQuery

        if(data.Count() > 0)
            return new Contacts(data);
        else
            return null;
    }
    catch(XmlRpcIllFormedXmlException)
    {
          // Ensure we have not hit maximum retries.
          // Sleep thread for 500ms to avoid hitting api limit (this is no the ui thread)
          // Swallow exception and retry.

    }
}
```

I just want to reiterate that this is NOT a problem with my code before anyone asks why data gets filled with a comment ;p This is just the general format of the wrapper for any call to the system.

I am also tracking retries in the actual code to avoid hitting API call limits.

(If this belongs on code review please move it! I felt it belonged on SO as it is kinda erroneous code ie using exceptions for control + infinite loops)

Comment: One web service I deal with does approximately the same thing, I have some more controls over it than just "loop until it succeeds". E.g. a limit to retries, as well as a "sleep" period between retries. Works "fine" in the sense that it reliably retrieves the data in all but the most extreme failures on behalf of the web service.

Comment: Why are you using XmlRpc to process SOAP?

Comment: Funnily enough our integration expert explained them as part of the same thing! After doing some research I actually meant RESTful and have altered the question accordingly.

Comment: @Hellfire: I'm sorry, but that still doesn't make sense. No `XmlRpc` service could be considered "RESTful".

Comment: @JohnSaunders: Ugh, I need to learn to read what I wrote instead of what I meant. One is restful the other is xmlrpc. The xmlrpc one is causing the issues. Have removed any mention of rest since its not actually relevant to the question, hope the intro is clearer now?